# Geolocation: How to derive the Country using an address/city/place?

Tags: geolocation, google-geolocation

I have a .csv file with Twitter profiles including information such as username, name, description etc. One column is `geolocation`. In this text the user may have a country (i.e., UK), a city or town (i.e., Cambridge), an actual address (5 Tyrian Place, WR5 TY1), a state (i.e, California, CA) or something silly (i.e., West of Hell).

Is there an API/library/automatic way of taking this information and deriving the country? For example, if the location is Cambridge the output should be UK, if the address is in the UK, the output should be UK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a reverse geocoding service which you can access through their Maps API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

They let you make 2500 free requests per day. One nice feature is it will give you correct latitude, longitude, state, country, etc  for things like "Golden Gate Bridge" and "The Big Apple." Twitter users enter all sorts of (sarcastic) phrases for their location -- like "West of Hell," "Mars," etc -- and Google will reverse geocode that as well. Though, that may not be very useful.

As another level of checking, you can compare the user's timezone ("utc_offset"), if it is present, to the place that Google returns. It's a bit involved and requires that you compare the timezone's latitude boundaries to the latitude and longitude in Google's response.